# Error with jQuery syntax {% %}

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having difficulties trying to figure out how this weird jQuery syntax works. Everything works except for when you get to the button click. I'm not sure how the {% %} stuff is supposed to work around a function like that. I am currently getting this console message: SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

My code:

```
// Check for new upload...if true refresh page
        {% if (file.new_up ) { %}
            {%=file.new_up=false%}
            {%=$("#no_ups").html("Your upload was successfully completed. <button>x</button>") %}
            {%=$("#no_ups").show("slow") %}

            {%=$("button").click(function ( )  { %}
              {%=$("#no_ups").hide("slow") %}
            {% }) %}

       {% } %}
```

Comment: what is the backend being used? looks like some kind of python backend.

Comment: This isn't a Jquery issue. It seems like a server-side script gone wrong.

Comment: It's in this script tag <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this instead of trying to mess with that server side code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#bClose').click(function () {
        $("#no_ups").hide("slow");
        $("#bClose").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```